# what is source model in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, model, source-model

Can anyone explain what is a source Model in Magento.

various time it was asked by interviewer ...but it was confusing for me...can any body explain.....
I need to know deeply about source model.. in Magento and its task.....
I know about resource model which is responsible for collection and model for basic logic...but source model I don not know.....pls help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A source model is the *source* of possible values for dropdown or multiselect form fields. Each value is a pair of actual value and displayed label. Source models are used for, but not limited to:

- system configuration values
- attribute values
- grid column filters
- custom Varien_Form instances

There are a few methods a source model should implement, depending on the context.
Magento 1 was not very keen on interfaces, so this is basically just a halfway consistent convention<sup>1</sup>. If you want to create a generic source model that can be used anywhere, make sure to implement them all:

- `toOptionArray()` returns an array of arrays, each must have the keys `label` and `value`. You can nest the arrays one level deeper to define `<optgroup>` groups
- `toOptionHash()` returns an associative array in the form `value => label`
- `getAllOptions($withEmpty)` same as `toOptionArray()`, but you can specify if an empty value with 'Please choose...' label is added.
- `getOptionText($value)` returns the label for a given value

---

<sup>1) There is `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Interface` but it is only sufficient for EAV attributes and not type hinted anywhere.</sup>

Comment: How can I override/rewrite the source models? e.g. Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet_Source_PaymentAction.  I'm not able to do it like other simple models.

Comment: But it is a normal model that should be referenced by its alias, so there is nothing special regarding rewriting it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically its just a list of options.

> Source Model – a model class that serves to get existing values
>   (stored in the db or somewhere else) for further displaying inside the
>   setting’s field.

- http://www.atwix.com/magento/frontend-backend-source/